# Trouble emitting information on clientside with socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am using express.js, mongoose, jquery and socket.io

I am trying to pass the object "allFightScores" to the socket on clientside. Here is where I am requesting information from mongoose in my routes/index.js:

```
var models = require('../models/index.js');
var passport = require('passport');
var crawl = require('../crawler.js');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

exports.submit_scores = function(req, res){

  var scored_fight = new models.UserScore({
    "f1": req.body.f1,
    "f2": req.body.f2,
    "f1_roundScores": req.body.f1_roundScores,
    "f2_roundScores": req.body.f2_roundScores,
    "f1_score": req.body.f1_score,
    "f2_score": req.body.f2_score,
    "user_email": req.body.user_email
  });

  models.UserScore.find({
    "f1": scored_fight.f1,
    "f2": scored_fight.f2,
    "f1_score": scored_fight.f1_score,
    "f2_score": scored_fight.f2_score,
    "user_email": scored_fight.user_email
  }, function(err, data){
    if (data.length === 0){
      scored_fight.save(function(err, user_fight){
        if (err) {
          return "error";
        }
        else {
          models.UserScore.find({"f1": user_fight.f1, "f2": user_fight.f2}, function(err, allFightScores){
            console.log("from index-routes " +allFightScores);
            io.sockets.emit('show scores', allFightScores)
          })
        }
      })
      //put a callback on the user_scored_fight data, also emit that data with the average scores;
      res.json(scored_fight);
    }
    else if (data[0].f1 === scored_fight.f1 && data[0].f2 === scored_fight.f2 && data[0].user_email === scored_fight.user_email) {
      res.json(200);
      console.log("data already judged.");
    }
  })
}
```

Here is where I am catching the data on my clientside (public/javascripts/script.js):

```
jQuery(function($){
  socket = io.connect();

  var $group_f1_score = $('#gf1_score');
  var $group_f2_score = $('#gf2_score');

  socket.on('show scores', function(mongooseData){
    console.log("mongooseData from scripts " + mongooseData)

    $group_f1_score.empty();
    $group_f2_score.empty();

  //sum fighter scores for all user submissions
    var f1_sumScore = 0;
    var f2_sumScore = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < mongooseData.length; i++){
      f1_sumScore += mongooseData[i].f1_score;
      f2_sumScore += mongooseData[i].f2_score;
    }
    //get the simple average
    var f1_avgScore = f1_sumScore/mongooseData.length;
    var f2_avgScore = f2_sumScore/mongooseData.length;

    $group_f1_score.append(f1_avgScore);
    $group_f2_score.append(f2_avgScore);
  })
})
```

I am not sure why the data is not emitting to my clientside and am out of ideas. Am I querying the data and passing it in the callback correctly?

Comment: what does the `socket.io` logs show? does it log incoming connection? does it log the message that it emits? it the query executed without errors?

Comment: @Phoenix It's not logging the message that it should emit. I think I'm not emitting properly in my routes/index.js file. Here's the full code on github, if you have a chance. https://github.com/kyu1012/FightScores

Comment: why are you creating a second http server, for serving socket.io? you should bind your socket.io with the express instance in `app.js` and not with routes/index.js.Try to handle incoming socket.io connections *outside* of the database callback place it before starting the http server.

Comment: @Phoenix - I'm not sure how else I would emit data from the database aside from calling socket.io in the controllers, inside the db callback. Do you have any suggestions? 

What I've done is:
1) require socket.io globally in app.js (line 27) 
2) remove the socket.io require in routes/index.js (line 10)

and it is emitting properly. What do you think of this?

Comment: looks good. When i said to handle incoming socket.io connections outside of db callback, i meant to more `io.sockets.on('connection'` to `app.js` but **emitting** should be called after database queried. _Note_ that you don't have to call `io.sockets.emit` when you send a request and database callback which in turn sends updates to sockets. Remember this not rely on that request in order to query your DB. You could make poll changes from database every X time, and send updates to all connected clients.

Comment: @Phoenix - ok, so I don't have to use `io.sockets.emit` to update my sockets with DB callback and I should establish socket.io connection in the `app.js` file. I understand the second part, but not the first part of my statement. How can I update sockets without using `io.sockets.emit`? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see this in your code:

```
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: I didn't include my server file above, but it's in my app.js file starting at line 81. Full code here: github.com/kyu1012/FightScores